# WebDeply - WDeployConfigWriter fails login. Not expired password

Tags: iis, msdeploy, windows-server-2016

Using Visual Studio 2019 to publish to Windows Server 2016, only preview and full publish failes. Single files publish fine. According to the logs the problem is that the wrong password for WDeployConfigWriter is used.

From the log wmscv tracing log:

```
Client IP: x.x.x.x
Content-Type: application/msdeploy
Version: 9.0.0.0
MSDeploy.VersionMin: 7.1.600.0
MSDeploy.VersionMax: 9.0.3802.0
MSDeploy.Method: Sync
MSDeploy.RequestId: 5adc40d9-416c-4a8f-a436-d9ba0d3cc58f
MSDeploy.RequestCulture: en-GB
MSDeploy.RequestUICulture: en-US
ServerVersion: 9.0.1994.0
Skip: objectName=&quot;^configProtectedData$&quot;objectname=&quot;dirPath&quot;,absolutepath=&quot;SiteName\\App_Data$&quot;
Provider: auto, Path: 
A tracing deployment agent exception occurred that was propagated to the client. Request ID &apos;5adc40d9-416c-4a8f-a436-d9ba0d3cc58f&apos;. Request Timestamp: &apos;17/03/2021 12:36:34&apos;. Error Details:
Microsoft.Web.Delegation.DeploymentAuthorizationException: Not able to log on the user &apos;.\WDeployConfigWriter&apos;. ---&gt; System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The user name or password is incorrect.
```

Publishing/previewing using an administrator user works fine, as does any publishing single files (with the non-admin user).

So far I've tried:

- Updating the password manually
- Running AddDelegationRules.ps1
- Running Repair from the Web Deply installer and rebooting the server
- Deleting all delegation rules and the WDeployConfigWriter user and running AddDelegationRules.ps1

Nothing helps or changes the error I get. Publishing using Web Deploy has been working fine on this server since 2018 until last month.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way to fix the problem:

- Computer Management ->Local Users And Groups -> Users
- Right click -> properties on WDeployAdmin
- Uncheck "User must changed password at next logon
- Check "Password never expires"
- Do the same for WDeployConfigWriter

Comment: I should probably elaborated the "Not expired password" from the title. The two users where already configured like you suggest when the problem started occurring.

Comment: Please recycle your application pool and try again. also make sure the user has assigned to Active Directory Browser permission in the security group.